# Determining why a .NET assembly/module was loaded

Tags: .net, dependencies, .net-assembly, assembly-loading

Much has been written on SO about debugging .NET assembly loading failures. In this case, an assembly loaded successfully. I want to know why it was loaded at all.

How can I determine the dependant(s)?

(Specifically, I have a WinForms application that's loading WPF assemblies that I don't think should be needed.)

Comment: If you remove the WPF assembly references from your WinForms application, does it still build?

Comment: Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad event and set a breakpoint on it.  The stack trace when it hits tells the tale.  You have to stay ahead of the jitter, so make it the first statement in Main().  You may have to move the code inside Main() into another method.